# Jquery .load, Post parameters, not being sent over local php server

Tags: php, jquery, post, intellij-idea, xampp

I have two files,
test.php

```
<html>
   <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="status">LOADING</div>
    <br/>
    <div id="div1"></div>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <div id="div2"></div>
    <script>
        $( "#div1" ).load( "sanity.php", "key=value"); // sent with GET
        $( "#div2" ).load( "sanity.php", {"key" : "value" }); // sent with POST
        $('#status').html("done");
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

and sanity.php

```
SOF
<table>
    <?php

    echo "<br/>";
    echo "POST:";
    var_dump($_POST);

    echo "<br/>";
    echo "GET:";
    var_dump($_GET);

    echo "<br/>";
    ?>
</table>
EOF
```

When I run them on my webserver, I get the (expected!) output,

```
done

SOF 
POST:array(0) { } 
GET:array(1) { ["key"]=> string(5) "value" } 
EOF


SOF 
POST:array(1) { ["key"]=> string(5) "value" } 
GET:array(0) { } 
EOF
```

But when I run them locally, I get

```
done

SOF 
POST:array(0) { } 
GET:array(1) { ["key"]=> string(5) "value" } 
EOF


SOF 
POST:array(0) { } 
GET:array(0) { } 
EOF
```

From LOADING turning into "done", I can see that the jQuery is running. The load is sending GET and POST depending on the format of the data being passed [doc](http://api.jquery.com/load/), i.e.

```
"key=value" - GET request
{"key" : "value"} - POST request
```

This has obviously something to do with the local PHP server I'm running, but I have no idea where to start looking, as I've never experienced anything like this before. I've tried searching for "local php server post not working", with variations including "XAMPP" and "intellij".

Implied, I'm using XAMPP, with PHP 7.0 interpreter in Intellij.

The headers being sent on the local server is almost identical to the ones being sent on the webserver, so the data is being passed, but it's simply not being picked up.

Thank you!

EDIT: the "enable_post_data_reading" directive in php.ini is enabled/on

Answer (score 0):

Apologies, it seems to be a standing bug in PHP Storm and Intellij IDEA, using the built in PHP server.

See: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206999125-PhPStorm-10-does-not-allow-POST-method?page=1

It seems it can be solved by using the xampp php server.